# Determinant properties when determinant is given and $n \times n$ is known

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$A$ and $B$ are $4\times 4$ matrices $(n=4)$ and $\det(A)= -2$, $\det(B)=3$.

What is $\det (A^3 \cdot \det(B^{-1}))$?

I'm not sure if the dot product comes into play in this exercise or if I follow the $\det(AB)= \det(A)\det(B)$ property. I understand that $\det(B^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det(B)}$, but I'm confused overall.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, $\det(B^{-1})$ is a real number, so $A\cdot\det(B^{-1})=\det(B^{-1})A$. The dot there is not technically a dot product, it's just plain multiplication.

Comment: "*dot product comes into play*"  There is no dot product here.  You dot product two vectors.  These are matrices.  That is just the usual matrix multiplication.

Comment: @user1172706 The answer is not $-\frac{8}{3}$. The answer should be $-\frac{8}{81}$.

Comment: Let $M$ be a matrix of dimension $n\times n$, and $a$ be a real number. Then $\det(aM) = a^n \det(M)$

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the determinant of $\frac{1}{3}A^3$.

This is just $(\frac{1}{3})^4$ multiplied by the determinant of $A^3$ and is therefore $\frac{-8}{81}$.

Answer (score 1):

It $k$ is a scalar and $M$ is a matrix, avoid writing $M\cdot k$: write $kM$ or $k\cdot M$ instead.

Said that, if $M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, $\det (kM)=k^n\det M$. Note that if you multiply a single row or column of a $n\times n$ matrix by a scalar, the determinat of the matrix becomes multiplied by this sclalar. So if you multiply every column (or row) of the matrix, the determinant becomes multiplied by $k$ $n$ times, that is, by $k^n$.

So,
$$\det(\det(B^{-1})\cdot A^3)=\det(B^{-1})^4\det(A)^3=-\frac{8}{81}$$